# how to detect which rows are shown in UItableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to update `accessoryViews` in `UITableView`, but just on the rows, which the user can actually see.

How can I detect which rows are actually on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of [UITableview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instance method `-visibleCells`

> ```
> visibleCells
> ```
>
> Returns the table cells that are
>   visible in the receiver.
>
> ```
> - (NSArray *)visibleCells
> ```
>
> **Return Value**
>
> An array containing `UITableViewCell`
>   objects, each representing a visible
>   cell in the receiving table view.
>
> **Availability**
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView has `-visibleCells` method for that - it returns a NSArray of currently visible cells

Answer (score 0):

Implement this for which row you want not to add accessory.

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
if (row == 0||row == 2)
    return nil;
return indexPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you really need to detect visible row for updating accessoryViews. You can just implement it in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` datasource method.

But if you want to get the visible rows you can use

```
- (NSArray *)visibleCells
```